# Would sea water moderate a nuclear submarine meltdown?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, water, nuclear-engineering

My son asked me:

> If nuclear submarines get sunk or blown up, what is to stop them going into nuclear meltdown?

I thought about it and came to the conclusion that because they're in the sea the water itself would act as a coolant, stopping nuclear meltdown. 
Is this correct, as I wouldn't want to teach him nonsense?

Comment: Please note that the word "moderate", in the context of nuclear power, does not usually mean "prevent, mitigate" - which seems to be the usage in your title. Instead, the ["moderator" in a nuclear reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_moderator) takes "fast" neutrons and turns them into "thermal" neutrons - making the chain reaction more likely to occur. There are also "[control rods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_rod)" which absorb the neutrons and act as a "brake" on the reaction.

Answer (score 2):

The word *meltdown* isn't strictly defined and can cover a range of sins from the core melting into a blob and down into the ground (as happened at Chernobyl) through to fuel elements melting (as happened at Fukushima).

At least two Russian submarines have experienced meltdowns, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_submarine_K-27) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_submarine_K-431), though this was while they were floating not when they were sunk.

The [Kursk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_submarine_Kursk_%28K-141%29#Submarine_recovery) was a nuclear submarine and it's reactor core was recovered more or less intact so any meltdown was minor if it happened at all. I suspect this was more to do with automatic safety features than the seawater as I would guess reactors are designed to keep water out. I suspect seawater would only be an effective coolant after a minor meltdown had punctured the pressure vessel.

Answer (score 2):

A meltdown is unlikely from either of those alone, but if there is damage to the control mechanisms - the control rods and the cooling systems - then it does become possible.

- Say it sinks due to a malfunction of, say, the ballast system. Then the crew would have time to insert the [control rods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_rod) in between the fuel rods in the reactor. This means that each rod can be considered by itself, and the reactor is very far from critical mass; there will not be a nuclear meltdown. Even if it sinks to some [very deep bottom](http://xkcd.com/1040/large/), and the pressure catastrophically crushes the hull, the rods are likely to remain in place. The rods remain isolated, and the pressure will not really affect the critical mass conditions. I imagine the water will act as a coolant but if the rods are properly inserted the reactor I would think the reactor should be safe.
- Say is blown up by some enemy torpedo. If the explosion is large enough, the fuel will likely be dispersed instead of concentrated, which will cause a heck of a lot of contamination but not a meltdown. On the other hand, military submarines may also be carrying a number of nuclear warheads; I am unsure whether a wholesale (conventional) explosion would set them off, but I wouldn't hold my breath: I would swim away as fast as I could.
- If there is only partial damage, though, there is a chance that the control rods be in an unsafe position (particularly when running at full power), and the damage prevents them from being reinserted. In that case, there is indeed a danger of a meltdown.

Like all nuclear reactors, nuclear submarines are always at risk of accidents that can lead to a meltdown (and like all modern nuclear reactors, this risk is very very very small). There have indeed been [a number of accidents on nuclear submarines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_submarine#Accidents), sometimes involving the reactor. Those include [K-27](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_submarine_K-27) and [K-431](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_submarine_K-431), which John mentioned, [USS *Thresher*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Thresher_%28SSN-593%29), which sank to the bottom, [K-19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_submarine_K-19), which came very close (through a coolant failure) to a meltdown and possibly a nuclear explosion, [K-219](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_submarine_K-219), which sank to the bottom, [USS *Scorpion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Scorpion_%28SSN-589%29), which also sank, and quite recently [*Kursk* (K-141)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_submarine_Kursk_%28K-141%29), which sank due to torpedo explosions.

As you can see, a little of everything has happened without any real meltdowns, and without real danger of one since the K-19. Thankfully, no nuclear submarine has been torpedoed out yet, but it is at least in theory possible that it could have rather catastrophic effects.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the water would act as a neutron moderator, speeding up the reaction. However, reactor pressure vessels are quite sturdy, and it would be very unlikely for the salt water to enter the pressure vessel.